# C++ reading large files part by part

Tags: c++

I've been having a problem that I not been able to solve as of yet. This problem is related to reading files, I've looked at threads even on this website and they do not seem to solve the problem. That problem is reading files that are larger than a computers system memory. Simply when I asked this question a while ago I was referred too using the following code.

```
    string data("");
getline(cin,data);
std::ifstream is (data);//, std::ifstream::binary);
if (is) 
{
    // get length of file:
    is.seekg (0, is.end);
    int length = is.tellg();
    is.seekg (0, is.beg);
    // allocate memory:
    char * buffer = new char [length];
    // read data as a block:
    is.read (buffer,length);
    is.close();
    // print content:

    std::cout.write (buffer,length);
    delete[] buffer;
}
system("pause");
```

This code works well apart from the fact that it eats memory like fat kid in a candy store. 
So after a lot of ghetto and unrefined programing, I was able to figure out a way to sort of fix the problem. However I more or less traded one problem for another in my quest.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
/*======================================================*/
    string *fileName = new string("tldr");
    char data[36];
    int filePos(0); // The pos of the file
    int tmSize(0); // The total size of the file    

    int split(32);
    char buff;
    int DNum(0);
/*======================================================*/



int getFileSize(std::string filename) // path to file
{
    FILE *p_file = NULL;
    p_file = fopen(filename.c_str(),"rb");
    fseek(p_file,0,SEEK_END);
    int size = ftell(p_file);
    fclose(p_file);
    return size;
}

void fs()
{
    tmSize = getFileSize(*fileName);
    int AX(0);
    ifstream fileIn;
    fileIn.open(*fileName, ios::in | ios::binary);
    int n1,n2,n3;
    n1 = tmSize / 32;

    // Does the processing
    while(filePos != tmSize)
    {
        fileIn.seekg(filePos,ios_base::beg);
        buff = fileIn.get();
        // To take into account small files
        if(tmSize < 32)
        {
            int Count(0);
            char MT[40];
            if(Count != tmSize)
            {
                MT[Count] = buff;
                cout << MT[Count];// << endl;
                Count++;
            }
        }
        // Anything larger than 32
        else
        {
            if(AX != split)
            {
                data[AX] = buff;
                AX++;
                if(AX == split)
                {

                    AX = 0;
                }
            }

        }
        filePos++;
    }
    int tz(0);
    filePos = filePos - 12;

    while(tz != 2)
    {
        fileIn.seekg(filePos,ios_base::beg);
        buff = fileIn.get();
        data[tz] = buff;
        tz++;
        filePos++;
    }

    fileIn.close();
}

void main ()
{
    fs();
    cout << tmSize << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

What I tried to do with this code is too work around the memory issue. Rather than allocating memory for a large file that simply does not exist on a my system, I tried to use the memory I had instead which is about 8gb, but I only wanted to use maybe a few Kilobytes of it if at all possible.
To give you a layout of what I am talking about I am going to write a line of text.
"Hello my name is cake please give me cake"
Basically what I did was read said piece of text letter by letter. Then I put those letters into a box that could store 32 of them, from there I could use something like xor and then write them onto another file. 
The idea in a way works but it is horribly slow and leaves off parts of files.
So basically how can I make something like this work without going slow or cutting off files. I would love to see how xor works with very large files.
So if anyone has a better idea than what I have, then I would be very grateful for the help.

Comment: I am a bit confused about using xor. How does this enter the story? Also I didnt find where you actually use xor in your code

Comment: I wanted to use Xor in this program later on, but I refrained from doing so in order to better understand some of the problems with the file reader. I do not however intend to limit the use of this code just for Xor, it more or less of an example of what could be applied too. I do apologize for not making that clearer. If I sounded rude at all in any of my responses or text I do also apologize for that, I simply want to be very clear.

Comment: I never realised that fat kids in candy stores were well known for eating memory.

Comment: Umm... I miss your point. 1st code example seems straight up bad. "*[...]reading files that are larger than a computers system memory.* [code] *This code works well apart from the fact that it eats memory like fat kid in a candy store.*" I means it doesn't work at all. `getline(cin,data);` reads whole file into memory. And your second code seems overly complicated, just for reading file in chunks.

Comment: @luk32: No it doesn't. It gets a line. The clue's in the name, really...

Comment: It is more of less of a metaphor, if you do find that offensive I do apologize.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Fair enough, though, the file seems to be binary. Then it makes even less sense to use it at all. And even if it is a text. It reads only one line. That is not file processing. Anyway, it is straight up bad.

Comment: getline(cin,data); was used for the file name rather than a constant string

Comment: I don't really see why #1 should leak memory (it is not optimal, but still). An optimal way would be to allocate 1 buffer outside the loop, avoid all the lseek stuff, don't close is after each read, and just read-length-bytes-from-fs - write-length-bytes-to-cout in the loop.

Comment: "[...] and then write them onto another file" - from your question, it's not clear to me what you're really trying to achive and you didn't show the code which should produce the output file you mentioned. Basically, it looks like you're trying to parse a input file line by line and output it (xor every letter??) to another file also line by line, but want to transform the line in between, f.e. by adding up all chars and xoring them? also, are you working towards puttng a ui like think between reading and writing?

Comment: What does your original program do with the data it reads from the file?

Comment: @luk32: I'm not saying this code makes sense :) Just that `getline` doesn't by definition retrieve a whole file.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Point taken, that was so stupid I decided to leave the comment unedited and bear the shame =)

Comment: I still didnt get what all this has to do with xor. Maybe xor really isnt part of the story but related to something else that you want to do with the contents of the file (which is not part of the code you show?) once reading and writing is working.

Answer (score 9):

To read and process the file piece-by-piece, you can use the following snippet:

```
// Buffer size 1 Megabyte (or any number you like)
size_t buffer_size = 1<<20;
char *buffer = new char[buffer_size];

std::ifstream fin("input.dat");

while (fin)
{
    // Try to read next chunk of data
    fin.read(buffer, buffer_size);
    // Get the number of bytes actually read
    size_t count = fin.gcount();
    // If nothing has been read, break
    if (!count) 
        break;
    // Do whatever you need with first count bytes in the buffer
    // ...
}

delete[] buffer;
```

The buffer size of 32 bytes, as you are using, is definitely too small. You make too many calls to library functions (and the library, in turn, makes calls (although probably not every time) to OS, which are typically slow, since they cause context-switching). There is also no need of tell/seek.

Comment: It works pretty well with regular text, but it flat out does not work on some binary files like exe's.

Comment: I am pretty sure it should work fine. Can you elaborate on how does it fail? Maybe the problem is with the processing?

Comment: If you read something like xor data it will only read an exceedingly small portion of it. The same applies with exe's

Comment: Well, I have just tried the code myself, and I can read executables without any problem. What operating system and compiler do you use? Maybe you have to specify `ios::binary` flag to the stream constructor.

Comment: outFile.write(buffer,count); I fixed the problem with that, the only issues I have now is performing an operation on the buffer multiple times so it effects all of the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need all the file content simultaneously, reduce the working set first - like a set of about 32 words, but since XOR can be applied sequentially, you may further simplify the working set with constant size, like 4 kilo-bytes.

Now, you have the option to use file reader `is.read()` in a loop and process a small set of data each iteration, or use `memmap()` to map the file content as memory  pointer which you can perform both read and write operations.

Comment: Thanks I might try that latter on but how might that look in code form.