# how can i address a character in a .txt file as i would do with an array in c++?

Tags: c++

Im new. I want to address a character in a .txt file as I would do in an array like this:

```
int a[100];
for(i=0; i<100; i++) {
   a[i]=x;
//or
   cin >> a[i];
//or
   cout >> a[i];
}
```

can I use this method to the .txt file? if I can do this with pointers, how?

Comment: You can read the file into an array (or better, string or vector).

Comment: I know, but I have to work with a huge database like 1 billion numbers and i have to do it with low ram usage.

Comment: One problem at a time. I suggest that you follow some online tutorials on reading large files in C++. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30619883/6334782) is an answer you can read on achieving just that.

Comment: Do you know the number of the characters

Comment: Memory map the file?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! how can i do that? i tried to get a pointer of the first character but it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in comments you can read the contents of that .txt file into a char array, and then work on that array data.

This answer [How to copy a .txt file to a char array in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398167/how-to-copy-a-txt-file-to-a-char-array-in-c/56726145) should show you how to do this.